# adding event to image in EaselJS

Tags: events, extjs, easeljs, listeners

I was hoping that I could get a little help with something I'm trying to do. I'm learning EaselJS, Extjs but still a little new. I'm trying to create an extJS window, inside the window I added a canvas which I use easelJS to manipulate. On a button1 I added an event handler that will overlay an image... what I am trying to do is make that overlayed image have events. In the long run I'd like to be able to highlight that image, and store the number of overlayed images from mouseclick onto that image.

here is my code

```
 var stage;
var overlay;
var overImage;
 var myImage;
var bgrd;
Ext.onDocumentReady( function () {




    //var myImage = new createjs.Bitmap("dbz.jpg");
    //stage.addChild(myImage);
    //stage.update();




    function setBG(){
              myImage = new Image();
              myImage.src = "dbz.jpg";
              bg();
              }

    function bg(){
              bgrd = new createjs.Bitmap(myImage);
              stage.addChild(bgrd);
              stage.update();
              }









Ext.define('EaselWindow', {

width: 1000,
height: 750,
extend: 'Ext.Window',
html: '<canvas id="demoCanvas" width="1000" height="750">'
    + 'alternate content'
    + '</canvas>',

afterRender: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);


    stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
            stage.onload = setBG();
      }, // end after render func
listeners: {

       click: {
           element: 'body',
           fn:    function(){
           var seed = new createjs.Bitmap("seed.jpg");
           seed.alpha = 0.5;
           seed.x = stage.mouseX-10 ;
           seed.y = stage.mouseY-10 ;
           stage.addChild(seed);
           stage.update();
                   } //end addeventlistener
              }

         },





  items:[{ 
       itemId: 'button1',
       xtype: 'button',
       text: 'click the button',
       visible: true,
       enableToggle: true,

       toggleHandler:
       function(button, pressed){
           if(button.pressed==true){
               overImage = new Image();
               overImage.src = "stuff.jpg";
               overlay = new createjs.Bitmap(overImage);

               stage.addChild(overlay);

               stage.update();
               }
            else
             {stage.removeChild(overlay);
             stage.update();
             }

        }// end func




        },{
        itemId: 'button2',
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'button2'

        }]

}); // end define

Ext.create('EaselWindow', {
title: "Ext+Easel",
autoShow: true,

 }); //end easelwindow

 overImage.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
                                        overlay.alpha=0.7;
                                        }); // this function isn't working 
});
```

edit to add:  itemId: 'button2',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'addSeed',
            enableToggle: true,
            handler: function(button, pressed){
               if(button.pressed==true){
                  bgrd.addEventListener('click', function(){
                           seed = new createjs.Bitmap("seed.jpg");
                   seed.alpha = 0.5;
                   seed.x = stage.mouseX-10 ;
                   seed.y = stage.mouseY-10 ;
                           storex= seed.x; 
                           storey= seed.y;
                           console.log(storex +","+ storey);
                           stage.addChild(seed);
                           stage.update();

```
                       })   

              } 

           } //end addeventlistener
```

but but once the button is pressed the ability to click remains on if w/ the if statement condition I don't understand why, is there a way to say else ( turn off)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add EventListeners in EaselJS as follows:

```
function bg(){
    bgrd = new createjs.Bitmap(myImage);

    bgrd.addEventListener('click', onClick);

    stage.addChild(bgrd);
    stage.update();
}

function onClick() {
    console.log('bgrd was clicked.');
}
```

This is btw. very well documented in the EaselJS-docs: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/EventDispatcher.html and there are tons of examples for this and most other cases you are looking for on Github at:

https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/examples
and
https://github.com/CreateJS/sandbox

Comment: I tried doing something like that at the end of my code, is there a way to put onClick to happen in like the listeners section of the button? I only want the bgrd.addEventListener('click', onClick); run when the button is pressed.

Comment: I added something like this

Comment: NVM got it with a remove listener ty :D